# Automating axis bank website

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I am trying to select Accounts that come under Products heading using Actions. Although it should have been done easily but i am unable to do same. Can anyone please help.

```
    [Account under Product heading][1]
    driver.get("http://www.axisbank.com/");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Actions action=new Actions(driver);
    WebElement account=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='product-menu']/div[2]/div/div/ul[1]/li[1]/a"));
    WebElement prod=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul[1]/li[1]/a"));
    action.moveToElement(prod).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    action.moveToElement(account).click().perform();
```

Comment: What is the actual problem / error?

Comment: You should indicate the failure messages.

Comment: Please include error/failure messages you are getting. This will help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: I am not getting any error message . The report shows the test has passed and clicked Accounts. but this is not happening

Comment: I just want this sequence of steps:
1. Open axis bank website.
2. Open Products dropdown
3. Open Accountts section in t
4. Click Savings account
5. Open Current Accounts section on next page
6.Select any option from listed ones.
Can any one please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This working example selects Products then Accounts in the menu:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.axisbank.com/");

// move the cursor to the menu Product
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#product span"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).perform();

// click on accounts
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".main-menu a[title=Accounts]")).click();
```